# Azure Cosmos Auto Scale using Java SDK v2 com.microsoft.azure.documentdb

Tags: java, api, azure-cosmosdb, autoscaling

I am not finding com.microsoft.azure.documentdb (2.6.1) Java API documentation supporting Auto scale in Azure Cosmos DB. Should I use Azure-cosmos Java library for leveraging auto scale capabilities as explained in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-autoscale-throughput?tabs=api-async)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package mentioned here,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
  <version>4.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/cosmos-readme?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 0):

Based on the release notes for [`SDK version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-async-java), I don't think it has support for autoscale. Autoscale however is supported in [`SDK version 4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-v4). Please use that instead of version 2.

To create a database with autoscale throughput, you will need to use [`createDatabase(CosmosDatabaseProperties databaseProperties, ThroughputProperties throughputProperties)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.createdatabase?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_cosmos_CosmosClient_createDatabase_com_azure_cosmos_models_CosmosDatabaseProperties_com_azure_cosmos_models_ThroughputProperties_) method.

Similarly to create a container with autoscale throughput, you will need to use [`createContainer(CosmosContainerProperties containerProperties, ThroughputProperties throughputProperties)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.cosmosdatabase.createcontainer?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_cosmos_CosmosDatabase_createContainer_com_azure_cosmos_models_CosmosContainerProperties_com_azure_cosmos_models_ThroughputProperties_) method.